# Must one add custom font file to info.plist in Xcode?

Tags: ios, uifont

Just a question about adding a custom font in Xcode. After I add it to my project's resources as a ttf file, I can use it inside a label in my storyboard for example. But do I need to add it to the info.plist file too?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you must add custom fonts to your Info.plist.  You do this with the `UIAppFont` Info.plist key (which shows up as `Fonts provided by application` in the plist editor).

Here is the [relevant documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW18).

And an example:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>SomeFont.otf</string>
    <string>SomeOtherFont.otf</string>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently done the same thing.

- Goto info.plist from project target.
- Add a new property by clicking `+`
- In the key section, write `Fonts provided by application`
- As it is an array of key-value pairs, you can add items under it.
- Unfold it to add the item for key `item-0`.
- `item-0` key can remain as it is. And give the value as font_name.otf.
- If you want to add more, just click `+` under `Fonts provided by application`. And it will create keys like `item-1, item-2 and so on.`